# Referencing the values in one array list to values in another

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there a data structure in Java where the values in one ArrayList can be used to reference the values in another? For example:

```
DataStructure<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> ds = new DataStructure<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>();
```

The purpose would be that I could iterate through the data structure later and get both values. For example:

```
for(int i=0; i<ds.size(); i++) {

     String val1 = ds.get(i).getIndex1().getArrayListValueAt(i);
     String val2 = ds.get(i).getIndex2().getArrayListValueAt(i);

}
```

I know this looks odd, but it's hard for me to picture.

P.S. Would it be easier to make sure the indexes are the same in both array lists and just loop through one, and as one is grabbed reference the same index in the other. For instance:

```
int i = 0;
for(String value : values) {
      String val1 = value;
      String val2 = list2.get(i);
      i++;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for Map data type ? which holds a Key and a corresponding value. API Link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: I found HashMap<String, String>, but when i watched a tutorial it said to get the values from the hash map i would use something like this. get("val1"); and it would return val2. But I would need to get both values at once. Is this the right structure to use, but I'm approaching wrong? or..

Comment: So you want to get a pair of values based on their index in a collection?

Comment: Are you looking for an indexed data structure that holds two string? If so, then you could have an array/list of String[2]

Comment: Yes to Zircon, and I think so to Stormcloud

Comment: @Kieran you can use any thing like `Map<List<String>, List<String>> map;` You can also use Pair object : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html but this will need a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your purpose, the `Map` structure would be better suited. It's a dictionary, so one value is the key and the other is its mapped value.

```
Map<String, String> ds = new HashMap<>();
```

Then to loop and access the values, you can use its `keySet()` method like so...

```
for (String k : ds.keySet()) {
    String key = k;
    String value = ds.get(k);
}
```

And to add new key/value pairs to the data structure, you use the `put(k, v)` method.

```
ds.put("thisIsAKey", "thisIsTheValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, it sounds like you wanna have a list which each element in the list would hold pair of values. Would below solution help?

// A class which holds two values...

```
class MyPair {
    String val1;
    String val2;
}
```

// And then you list would be ..

```
List<MyPair> myList = new ArrayList();
```

// When you looping your list... it would be like something below

```
for(MyPair mypair : myList) {
     String val1 = mypair.val1;
     String val2 = mypair.val2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. `Map` for your problem, because you can storage all needed collection in one place

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

or e.g.:

```
Map<List<String>, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And then you can e.g. `String` as key and e.g. `List<T>` as value

Very important thing is which object do you use as key, because it must have equals/hashCode (if is your object it must be `@Override`) and next, great when this object is immutable